# GLib create new type

Tags: glib, gobject

How to create new type using GLib?

I have created this program:

```
struct stock_element {
   GType type;
   GtkTreeIter *iter;
   GtkListStore *model;
};
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   GType a =g_type_register_static_simple (G_TYPE_OBJECT,
                           "type_select_item",
                           sizeof(GTypeClass) + sizeof(GObject),
                           NULL,
                           sizeof(struct stock_element),
                           NULL,
                           0);
  }
```

But I got this warning:GLib-GObject-WARNING **: specified class size for type 'type_select_item' is smaller than the parent type's 'GObject' class size

Comment: Are you trying to make a subclass of GObject? In that case you should look at G_DEFINE_TYPE* macros that do the type registering for you. Your example doesn't really make sense to me...

Answer (score 2):

If you insist in using `g_type_register_static_simple`, at least use it properly.

You must define two different structs: the class and the instance. These are fundamental concepts of any object-oriented implementation I'm aware of, they are not specific to GTK+.

If you are inheriting `GObject`, you **must** use it as the first field in your structs. Not sure where you got the idea of using `GType`.

```
struct StockElementClass {
    GObjectClass gobject_class;
};

struct StockElement {
    GObject gobject;
    GtkTreeIter *iter;
    GtkListStore *model;
};
```

Only then you can register your own type.

```
GType a = g_type_register_static_simple(G_TYPE_OBJECT,
                                        "StockElement",
                                        sizeof(struct StockElementClass),
                                        NULL,
                                        sizeof(struct StockElement),
                                        NULL,
                                        0);
```

The fact that your code is working is only a coincidence because you provided enough space for allocating class and instance structs. The following (wrong) code works because of the same coincidence:

```
g_type_register_static_simple(G_TYPE_OBJECT, "StockElement",
                              1234, NULL, 1234, NULL, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can see some of my work, first .h:

https://github.com/benoitfragit/pocketVox/blob/master/src/lib/pocketvox-module.h

then .c file:
https://github.com/benoitfragit/pocketVox/blob/master/src/lib/pocketvox-module.c

Here I create a new type PocketvoxModuel using the bollertemplate code

Answer (score -3):

I found solution:
    type_select_item = g_type_register_static_simple (G_TYPE_OBJECT,
                               "type_select_item",
                               sizeof(GTypeClass) + sizeof(GObjectClass),
                               NULL,
                               sizeof(struct stock_element),
                               NULL,
                               0);

Comment: You shouldn't have to use `g_type_register_static_simple`; instead use `G_DEFINE_TYPE(type_select_item, TypeSelectItem, G_TYPE_OBJECT)` as jku suggests.